# How to mount 3rd party script in React?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, reactjs

I am building a website using React and a Wordpress REST API. I am trying to load ads from JuicyAds which loads a window object that I mount on a div.

So far, I used a wordpress-react boilerplate that makes it easy to upload a custom theme. However, I would much rather simply use create-react-app. But so far the script has only been able to load through the index.php. The problem with this is that the script is loaded for every single page instead of the pages it needs to load.

I cannot get the window object to be available through React. I have tried several solutions but cannot get this to work.

When I have access to the window object I cannot mount it to the div through the React component. It works if I put all of the logic in index.php.

Does anyone know how to do this? I imagine it should be a relatively simple solution but haven't gotten anything to work.

This is the ad I am trying to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false" async src="https://adserver.juicyads.com/js/jads.js"></script>
<ins id="770122" data-width="300" data-height="262"></ins>
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false" async>(adsbyjuicy = window.adsbyjuicy || []).push({'adzone':770122});</script>
```

Comment: As a bandaid, you can probably throw an if statement on index.php to only put the code on pages that need it based on the $_REQUEST global.

Comment: Fair idea but react doesn’t truly refresh the page moving from link to link so the session variable doesn’t change

Comment: index.php is on the server. It has nothing to do with react.

Comment: True but the $_REQUEST global only changes on a manual refresh

Comment: ah using <a> instead of <Link> refreshes the page making the globals usable!!

Comment: FYI: The react way to do this would be to hit an api with an ajax request in a hook or componentDidMount to get the update.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Can you elaborate on the ajax solution? Id much prefer to do it the react way

Comment: I can't write one now, but if you search google for "react hooks api example" something will come up for sure.